# Cannot get '#' symbol in Controller using Spring @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, url, encoding, character-encoding

I have the following request Url /search?*charset*=UTF-8&q=C%23C%2B%2B.
My controller looks like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "q")
public String refineSearch(@RequestParam("q") final String searchQuery,....
```

and here i have searchQuery  = 'CC++'.
'#' is encoded in '%23' and '+' is '%2B'.
Why searchQuery does not contain '#'?

[searchQuery in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv4wg.png)

Comment: Because `#` is used in HTML to make sharp anchor, so it have an usecase in URL and to avoid missmatch it have to be escaped the rest of the time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But are there any solutions  to get '#' in controller?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. I got 'C#C++'. How do you display value of searchQuery?

Comment: Just checked in debug mode,here value of searchQuery is 'CC++

Comment: @AlexFilatov i attached a screen shot in my question atop

Comment: What web server and Spring (Boot?) version do you use?

Comment: You can add regexp in the URL matcher of the controller.

Comment: @AlexFilatov Tomcat 7.0 and  4.3.17.RELEASE SpringBoot

Comment: Couldn't reproduce with these versions as well (used standalone Tomcat 7.0.96 and Spring Boot 1.5.13.RELEASE which depends on 4.3.17.RELEASE Spring)

Comment: Can you create minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AlexFilatov Thank you very much for your help.My project is on Hybris platform ,maybe the problem with some features in it .Though i had checked hybris urlEncoders and filters before asked this question here.Okay,will continue investigating this issue

Comment: I'll try to create minimal reproducible example

Comment: Outside the project this works fine.So seems to be that problem is in Hybris platform

Comment: @AlexFilatov this happens when ServletRequest is wrapped in XSSRequestWrapper.For example ServletRequest xssSer = new XSSRequestWrapper(req,lazyValueTranslator);
xssSer.getParameter("q") = "C"    But HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
httpServletRequest.getParameter("q") = "C#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a problem.In filters chain ServletRequest is wrapped in XSSRequestWrapper with DefaultXSSValueTranslator and here is the method String stripXSS(String value) which iterates through pattern list,in case if value matches with pattern, method will delete it.
Pattern list contains "\u0023" pattern and '#' will be replaced with ""

```
DefaultXSSValueTranslator.
    private String stripXSS(String value) {
        Pattern scriptPattern;
        if (value != null && value.length() > 0) {
            for(Iterator var3 = this.patterns.iterator(); var3.hasNext(); value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("")) {
                scriptPattern = (Pattern)var3.next();
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a similar problem by URL encoding the hash part. We have Spring web server and mix of JS and VueJS client. This fixed my problem:

```html
const location = window.location;
const redirect = location.pathname + encodeURIComponent(location.hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

The main cause is known as the "fragment identifier". You find more detail for Fragment Identifier right [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). It says:

> The fragment identifier introduced by a hash mark # is the optional last part of a URL for a document. It is typically used to identify a portion of that document.

When you write # sign, it contains info for clientbase. Put everything only the browser needs here. You can get this problem for all types of URI characters you can look [Percent Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for this. In my opinion The simple solution is character replacing, you could try replace in serverbase.

Comment: He _does_ use URL encoding: C%23C%2B%2B